# Displaying data in a webpage from logged text files

Tags: php, logging, graph, html

I have multiple text files with logged data like this:

```
6/23/09 17:00 0.443
6/23/09 17:05 0.443
6/23/09 17:10 0.443
6/23/09 17:15 0.443
6/23/09 17:20 0.443
6/23/09 17:25 0.443
6/23/09 17:30 0.443
        ...
```

I'd like to create a webpage that displays this data from different files in a more readable manner. I'd like to create a scrollable datatable and a graph. I would like to only present one file at a time, so I would have a dropdown to select which one to view.

I have experience with HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP, and a little bit of MySQL as far as web stuff goes.

Currently, I'm planning on using a table in a fixed-height div for the datatable, but I'm not sure about the graph. Everything is up in the air.

**My questions:**

- What do you suggest I use to create this data viewer? (languages)
- What library should I use for graphing?
- What should I use for the scrollable datatable?
- How should I store the data? (Each file could have as many as 80,000 lines)

Any help would be great! I just need a point in the right direction.

Comment: Are the log files always in the above format?

Comment: The files will have three lines of header information for me to grab for the webpage, but the rest of it will be just as shown above. The datatable will only have the above data (date, time, and data with 3 digits after the decimal point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - What do you suggest I use to create this data viewer? (languages)

You already know PHP, HTML & CSS, so you could use HTML tables to begin with.

> - What library should I use for graphing?

There are several chart/graph libraries available, have a look at these questions:

- [Graphs/Charts in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395541/graphs-charts-in-php)
- [Best graph and diagram toolset for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110839/best-graph-and-diagram-toolset-for-php)

> - What should I use for the scrollable datatable?

Have a look at the [TinyTable JavaScript Table Sorter](http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/table-sorter/) if you use HTML tables.

> - How should I store the data?

You could import the files into a database.  Then use SQL queries to extract the information for the graphs as required.

Comment: Very helpful to get me started. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy, you might consider using Jasper Reports for the graphing.

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports

However that does require a little Java coding.  I definitely try the PHP graphic functions first and see how far you get with that.